# SQL help and advice referencing primary keys

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Im not sure what this means because it's extremely vague

[the problem is where I try to reference the attribute to another table and it is the primary key of another table.

It also a subclass:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not referencing your foreign key the right way. 
Try this:

```
FOREIGN KEY (Username) REFERENCES Owne(Username)
```

Comment: i used it worked but i got another error message about an expected symbol but nothing is incorrect in the lines, so im lost as to what it could be.

Comment: i got passed that part from earlier but i am on a new part where i need to make two attributes a foreign keys. i tried the ADD CONSTRAINT twice and then as one line

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint on username attribute, use this syntax:

```
FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES owner (username)
```

See this manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html